# Read messages concurrently from multiple kafka topics

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have a Kafka consumer who is listening to 3 topics. I have set the Concurrency value as 3. Will it create 3 consumer or 3 threads and Will it consume messages from each topic parallelly and process parallelly?

```
@Bean
public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {
    Map<String, Object> configs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    configs.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootStrapServer);
    configs.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupId);
    configs.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, enablAutoCommit);
    configs.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, maxPolInterval);
    configs.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, autoOffsetReset);
    configs.put(ConsumerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, clientId);
    configs.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    configs.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    return configs;
}

@Bean
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String>();
    // Not sure about the impact of this property, so going with 1
    factory.setConcurrency(3);
    factory.setBatchListener(true);
    factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(AckMode.MANUAL);
    factory.getContainerProperties().setConsumerRebalanceListener(RebalanceListener.getInstance());
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
    factory.getContainerProperties().setMessageListener(new BatchAckConsumer());
    return factory;
}
```

Comment: check - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55023240/when-to-use-concurrentkafkalistenercontainerfactory